# I do not understand some details in sections 9 and 10 of "A Painless Guide to CRC Error detection algorithms"

Tags: crc

The guide mentioned in the title (downloaded from http://ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt) has perfectly helped me grasp the principle, and the manual implementation, of a CRC algorithm. In sections 9 and 10 I hit what probably are minor snags.

The detail I do not understand in section **9. A Table-Driven Implementation**, where message bytes are shifted into a register from the right,  is in this part (emphasis in quotations is mine):

> • The top byte of the register now doesn't matter. No matter how many times and at what offset the poly is XORed to the top 8    bits, they will all be shifted out the *right hand side* during the next 8 iterations anyway.

> • The remaining bits will be shifted *left* one position and the rightmost byte of the register will be shifted in the next byte

I would think "right hand side" should be "left hand side" in the first bullet point?

In section **10. A Slightly Mangled Table-Driven Implementation**,
about dealing with the issue of appending zero bytes to the end of the message to be checked, I am confused by the following:

> The trouble, you see, is that this loop operates upon the AUGMENTED message and in order to use this code, you have to append **W/8** zero bytes to the end of the message before pointing p at it.

That is perfectly clear (the polynomial has width 32), but in the code that follows, and further down in the section, the author uses W/4:

`for (i=0; i<W/4; i++) r = (r << 8) ^ t[(r >> 24) & 0xFF];`

I would think that this should also have W/8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are typos in that text file. The top byte matters, since each non-zero bit results in the polynomial being xor'ed to the register, and the bits at that point are being shifted to the left. W/4 should be W/8, but it's not used in the later example code that xor's data with the top byte of the register to index the table, decrements `len` which is a count of bytes and increments `p` which is a pointer to a byte:

```
r=0; while (len--) r = (r<<8) ^ t[(r >> 24) ^ *p++];
```

Comment: Thank you. I think the wording about the top byte not mattering is unfortunate, as only the word "now" indicates that this refers to the situation where the control byte has already been calculated from the top byte so that the top byte has already had its relevance.

Comment: @jerdenberg - true, as it could be stated that none of the bytes matter after they have been processed, so what was the point of that statement?

Comment: The point is unclear indeed. I think the author switched, between sections 8 and 9, from meticulous step-by-step exposition to big steps where any problematic/superfluous statements are not exposed as they would be if, for instance, an example control byte was constructed as explicitly as was the division in section 6.